# How to drop the incoming packet from openVswitch integration bridge for specific IP?

Tags: centos, openstack, openflow, openvswitch

I have installed the openvSwitch server on my two centos server (KVM). I have created two VM’s and bridged using openvSwitch.  I am able to ping between the two VM’s. I am using VLAN for differentiating the private network.

Below is the VM IP
VM1 IP : 198.0.0.2  (resides in host1)
VM2 IP : 198.0.0.3 (resides in host2)

VLAN: 1000

I have followed the steps from the below link to configure the openvSwitch and it works fine.
http://openvswitch.org/support/config-cookbooks/vlan-configuration-cookbook/

Now I want to block few ports. I want to block the incoming traffic to the port 443, 80 for the VM1.  One option is I can modify the iptables in my VM to drop the traffic to the ports. But I don’t want to modify the firewall rules in the VM. I want to drop the packets from the OVS integration Bridge itself.

Thanks,
Kalpeer